# Parallelization of Intel Fortran code for allocatable type containing pointer arrays using OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I am trying parallelization of a part of code containing nested do loop. There is a 'READ' operation within the nested loop. I am trying to use openMP to reduced the wall time for computation. 
I have a type which contains allocatable pointer. I'm not sure how to handle the error message I'm getting "attempt to use pointer CellArr when it is not associated with a target" when I'm trying to use 
`P_ph(iph,iel)%cellArr(igp)%arr` outside this nested loop.

```
OPEN (24, FILE=TRIM(ADJUSTL(InpFile))//"_GSP.dat", STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ', &
ACCESS='DIRECT', FORM='FORMATTED', RECL=600*nel)   

!$omp parallel private(id,iel,iph,igp,igp1,tmpP,lineNo,isegel,iSegEls,ngp,ngp1,P_ph, &
  isegelTmp, igpTmp, phPolVec, integrand) shared(ShapeFunc_P, ElConn, nph) 
id=omp_get_thread_num()
!$omp do
DO iel = 1, nel     
    ngp = elConn(iel)%ngp   

    DO iph = 1, nph  
        ALLOCATE( P_ph(iph, iel)%cellArr(ngp) ) 
    END DO 

    DO igp = 1, ngp                
       lineNo = SUM( elConn(1:iel-1)%ngp ) + igp        
        READ(24,FMT=101,REC=lineNo ) isegelTmp, igpTmp, phPolVec

        DO iph = 1, nph     
           ALLOCATE( P_ph(iph,iel)%cellArr(igp)%arr(ndim,ndim) )
           tmpP = 0.d0 

           DO isegels = 1, Seg_P(iph)%segSize                   
              isegel = Seg_P(iph)%els(isegels)              
              ngp1 = elConn(isegel)%ngp                 
              ALLOCATE( integrand(ngp1) )           
              !Retrieve the PhP function from .dat file             
              phP = RESHAPE( SOURCE = phPolVec((isegel-1)*ndim*ndim+ &
              1:isegel*ndim*ndim ),SHAPE=(/ndim,ndim/) ) / elConn(isegel)%vol       

              DO igp1 = 1, ngp1             
                 ALLOCATE( integrand(igp1)%arr(ndim,ndim) )             
                 integrand(igp1)%arr = phP*ShapeFunc_P(isegel)      
              END DO   

              CALL INTEGRAL( tmpP, integrand, elConn(isegel)%jacobian, ngp, nsd, ndim)      

              DO igp1=1, ngp1           
                 DEALLOCATE( integrand(igp1)%arr )      
              END DO        
              DEALLOCATE(integrand) 
           END DO 

           P_ph(iph,iel)%cellArr(igp)%arr = tmpP
       END DO
     END DO
END DO
!$omp end do
!$omp end parallel
CLOSE (24)
```

The types are as follows:

```
TYPE CELL
    REAL*8, POINTER :: arr(:,:) 
END TYPE CELL 
TYPE CELL2  
    TYPE (CELL), POINTER :: CellArr(:) 
END TYPE CELL2
TYPE (CELL2) :: P_ph(nph, nel)
```

This code works fine as a sequential program.

Comment: `P_ph` should be shared, as you access its elements from all arrays.

Comment: Is Fortran I/O guaranteed to be thread safe? I'd definitely check that before going much further - my guess is not

Comment: Also check SHARED (nel, ndim, nsd, P_ph, Seg_P) PRIVATE (phP). DEFAULT (NONE) is a good diagnostic. P_ph is continually growing with ALLOCATE

Comment: @PierredeBuyl: Thanks. With your suggestion I am no longer getting the error message. However, the result seems not to be thread safe.

Comment: @IanBush: The result is not thread safe.

Comment: I have no direct source for this, but I guess that file I/O in an OpenMP region is a *bad* idea anyway. Can you read the data beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense that any thread could act on an arbitrary record in the file on unit 24 ?
If it does it would probably be better to place the read in a !$OMP CRITICAL region.

I also notice that the file is FORMATTED and DIRECT, with access via REC=lineNo and RECL=600*nel. (Unusual record size, is this running ? File size is 600*nel * sum(elConn(1:nel)%ngp), which looks very big order(nel^2).

It may be better to create this information as a shared derived type array of (isegelTmp, igpTmp, phPolVec), before entering !$OMP region and then process "randomly" from any thread. (No indication of the type or size of these 3 components.)
What is the record id : SUM( elConn(1:iel-1)%ngp ) + igp? Does it vary while processing (probably not)? Perhaps better to also create a shared index for the first record of each  "iel", before entering !OMP region and use this to define the work for each "iel" by any thread.
Where is all the information for each "iel" ? on another shared direct access file ?

I have not answered the question if reading a direct access file randomly by multiple threads is thread-safe? I have not tried this, but !$OMP CRITICAL would be a minimum. You could try a test. (lots of disk buffer clashes) Much safer to create a shared in-memory data structure first. Hopefully each iel processing time is much longer than the reading time.
Where do the processed results go ? to the same direct access file ? Kicking the problem down the road ?

This looks like a result processing loop. In my analysis, I have not moved this to !$OMP, as this result processing tends to be much quicker that the results calculation phase. With 64-bit, I have certainly moved the generated results to memory, rather than process from disk.